# Mocha tests fail when Wifi is disconnected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, mocha.js

I have some mocha tests that complete without errors when connected to Wifi. I am running the tests using command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive -R spec path/to/bootstrap.integration.js path/to/testfile.test.js
```

When I turn off the Wifi connection, the same tests fail in the before bootstrap with this error:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/resolv.conf'
```

I actually connect to the internet via a vpn and when the vpn is disconnected, but the wifi is still turned on and connected, the tests all pass. The firewall only allows outbound connections over the vpn.

Stepping through the code in the debugger, the error is thrown right after I clear out the database (mongodb).

Relevant code that gets called in the bootstrap file before:

```
  function emptyCollection(collectionName, callback) {
    debug(`emptying collection: ${collectionName}`);

    models[collectionName].deleteMany({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { // <--- Never reached when Wifi is disconnected
        return callback(err);
      }
      debug(`emptied collection: ${collectionName}`);
      return callback(null, result);
    });
  }

  debug('emptying all collections...');

  async.map(Object.keys(models), emptyCollection, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { // <--- Never reached when Wifi is disconnected
      return cb(err);
    }
    debug('emptied all collections');
    return cb();
  });
```

None of the deleteMany callbacks are ever reached when Wifi is disconnected. The async.map callback is never reached either.

I've been trying to find a way to set a breakpoint on when '/etc/resolv.conf' gets opened so I can determine which part of the code is trying to read the file, but I haven't found a way to do that.

I've been looking at this for hours, I'm all out of ideas.

Does any body have any troubleshooting advice?

[Update: I am looking for troubleshooting advice specific to the problem described above]

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are dependent on wifi or any network calls then you're not writing your tests in correct manner. Read this  - [F.I.R.S.T principle](https://github.com/ghsukumar/SFDC_Best_Practices/wiki/F.I.R.S.T-Principles-of-Unit-Testing)

Comment: thanks for the link - yes I know there is an issue with the tests, any idea how best to determine the root cause in this case?